# How to upload image from react-native without using base64?

Tags: react-native

For a project we need to upload an image file which has memory above 2mb.\
which we are not able to upload through base64 conversion.

Any help could be usefull

Comment: why not use [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob)

Answer (score 2):

Once you have your local image url using `ImagePicker` or some another solution, here's how you can send it to your server:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("image", { uri: imageUrl, name: 'image.jpg', type: 'multipart/form-data' })

fetch(yourUrl, {
    method: "POST", {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
    body: formData
);
```

Comment: The search I did to find this answer! GOD BLESS YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Use any request library e.g `axios` . Then try with form data. To pick the image from device/camera you can use `react-native-image-picker`.

```
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker'

ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {
          console.log(response.data)

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is what helped me.

1. In android/app/src/main/java/com/{yourProject}/MainApplication.java
   comment the below line :

   ```
   initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager())
   ```
2. In android/app/src/debug/java/com/{yourProject}/ReactNativeFlipper.java
   comment in line 43 :

   ```
   builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new FlipperOkhttpInterceptor(networkFlipperPlugin));
   ```
3. Code for image upload :

   ```
   var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('UserId', 'abc@abc.com');
      formData.append('VisitId', '28596');
      formData.append('EvidenceCapturedDate', '09/10/2019 13:28:20');
      formData.append('EvidenceCategory', 'Before');
      formData.append('EvidenceImage', {
        uri: Platform.OS === 'android' ? `file:///${path}` : path,
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        name: 'image.jpg',
      });
      axios({
        url: UrlString.BaseUrl + UrlString.imageUpload,
        method: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
      })
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log('*****handle success******');
          console.log(response.data);

        })
        .catch(function (response) {
          console.log('*****handle failure******');
          console.log(response);
        });
   ```